# Django: How to access session data from views.py created outside of views.py

Tags: python, django, session, jwt

I need to pass a jwt token generated in backend.py to views.py.

In backend.py i save it like this:

```
s = SessionStore()
s['id_token'] = id_token
s.create()
key1 = s.session_key
```

in views.py i try to get the session_key from that session like

```
key2 = request.session.session_key
```

But the two keys differ. What am i doing wrong and how can i access

> s['id_token']

in views.py?

Comment: Have you tried something like ```key2 = request.session.get('id_token', None)```?

Comment: it cant be none because it has to return something if 'id_token' doesnt exist. And it does not exist in my case, because the session in views.py is a different one than the one from backend.py